Using std::thread and native_handle() to set thread affinity mask
Is this the right way to create a thread and set the affinity using std::thread ?
std::thread myThread(threadFunction);

HANDLE threadHandle = myThread.native_handle();

SetThreadAffinityMask(threadHandle, 1);


Please read this: How do I ask a good question?

You should specify the compiler and/or standard library implementation you are asking about. Any use of native_handle() is implementation-defined. I tagged windows at least, because that looks like a Windows API.

What compiler are you using? VS2022 doesn't support C++11 so I'm guessing you are using a different compiler.

Looks ok.  Test whether SetThreadAffinityMask succeeded

I removed the myThread.join() call from the end of your example. I did it for two reasons: (1) joining the thread had no relevance to the question that you asked, and (2) with no other statements between the SetThreadAffinityMask(...) and the join call, it actually was an example of an anti-pattern. It never makes sense to spawn a new thread if the caller does not then do some kind of work concurrently with the new thread before the caller eventually joins it.

@TedLyngmo what do you mean by "VS2022 doesn't support C++11"? Are you saying vcpp doesn't implement the standard correctly?

@AluanHaddad I mean that there's no way to put it in C++11 mode, so you can't use a function like std::gets (which is a good thing). The options are C++14, 17, 20 and latest.

@TedLyngmo thank you. I agree that it's well that people won't end up programming against an obsolete version but I still miss the days when Microsoft actually cared about bc. When Microsoft actually cared about backwards compat (I should have learned my lesson after win RT).

Yes, that is correct.
In case you want to set it back to the original at some point, SetThreadAffinityMask also returns the old mask:
HANDLE threadHandle = myThread.native_handle();

DWORD_PTR new_mask = 1;
DWORD_PTR old_mask = SetThreadAffinityMask(threadHandle, new_mask);

In case old_mask is zero, setting the affinity failed.
